# Generate ascii doc api documentation from spring rest docs

Tags: java, spring, asciidoctor, spring-restdocs

Using Spring rest docs, you can generate a nice series of asciidocs as individual snippets.

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-docs does a good job in describing the process that I followed.

After the snippets are generated, I used, per the tutorial, [asciidoctor-maven-plugin](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-plugin) to combine them into a single file for documentation.

**Is there a way to generate a single .adoc file instead of the before mentioned html file?**

In the configuration, it allows you to specify the "backend" with:

```
<backend>html</backend>
```

http://asciidoctor.org/docs/convert-documents/#selecting-an-output-format
https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-plugin

...but I want to keep asciidoc as the final file format.

The closest comment that I have found is: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/168#issuecomment-58861372

...but I don't quite understand how to apply it to my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your link correct you can not use the provided solution with the maven plugin. At the moment it does not support to export asciidoctor-files. You have to

1. install ruby and the ascidoctor gem
2. download the script https://raw.githubusercontent.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-extensions-lab/master/scripts/asciidoc-coalescer.rb
3. run the script with ruby asciidoc-coalescer.rb your_file_name.adoc > single_file.adoc
4. pray that the script works and you don't run into the troubles the thread you posted mentioned. Your output should be in single_file.adoc

Comment: Thank you for your response. It solidified that I needed to look for a different solution.